# QChart диаграммы не имеет атрибута axisXx

Tags: python, pyqt5, qchartview, qdatetime, qchart

Сделал линейный график, по оси `х` - индексы, по `у` - значения линии.

Сделал дополнительно ось `QDateTimeAxis`, 
так как по оси `х` мне нужны не индексы, а время("`yyyy-MM-dd`").

`scrollbar` - прокручивает только ось с индексами, а `QDateTimeAxis` нет.

---

Если обратиться к оси `QDateTimeAxis`:

```
#self._chart.axisXx(self._line_tme).setRange(qt[value_min], qt[value_max])
```

то выходит ошибка:

> QChart диаграммы не имеет атрибута axisXx

---

Файл с данными для отрисовки находится здесь [**файл**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nzfD9K1ROEMXU4MKWoLSfp13CxUuyMSN/view)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
import math
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                 index_col='DATE',
                 parse_dates=True,
                 infer_datetime_format=True)

date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
x = len(z)
x_ = x - 1

qt = [None] * x

for i in range(0, x):
   qt[i] = QDateTime(date[i]).toMSecsSinceEpoch()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 30
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )

        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for w in (self._chart_view, self.scrollbar):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        self._line_time = QtChart.QLineSeries()

        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            c_ = z[i]
            self._line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, c_))
            self._line_time.append(qt[i], c_)

        min_x, max_x = 0, x_
        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_serie)
        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_time)

        axisX = QValueAxis()
        axisX.setLabelFormat("%d")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._line_serie.attachAxis(axisX)

        axisY = QValueAxis()
        #axisY.setLabelFormat("%f")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self._line_serie.attachAxis(axisY)

        axisXx = QDateTimeAxis()
        axisXx.setTickCount(5)
        axisXx.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisXx, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._line_time.attachAxis(axisXx)

        self._chart.legend().hide()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.lims = np.array([min_x, max_x])
        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())
        self.adjust_axes(1, 31)

    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        if value_min > 0 and value_max > 0 and value_max <= x_ and value_max > value_min:
            self._chart.axisX(self._line_serie).setRange(value_min, value_max)
            #self._chart.axisXx(self._line_tme).setRange(qt[value_min], qt[value_max])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `self._chart.axisXx(self._line_tme).setRange(qt[value_min], qt[value_max])`  на `self._chart.axisX(self._line_time).setRange( 
                QDateTime(date[value_min]), QDateTime(date[value_max]))` .  Обратите внимание: `axisXx <-> axisX`. `_line_tme <-> _line_time`, `qt[...] <-> QDateTime(date[...])`

Comment: Спасибо! Стало работать. Убрал серию "self._line_serie" оставив только "self._line_time" с осями axisXx = QDateTimeAxis() и axisY = QValueAxis().

Comment: как вы считаете я могу оформить мое предложение как ответ или не стоит ?

Comment: Да, оформляйте. У меня еще есть на английском вопрос по свечному графику. У меня там получается, только если еще добавить вторую серию с линейным графиком. Которую потом скрываю.

Comment: Вопрос на английском сейчас дополню.

Comment: я конечно и на том сайте бываю, но реже. Оформите свой вопрос на ru.SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить строку:

```
self._chart.axisXx(self._line_tme).setRange(qt[value_min], qt[value_max])
```

на:

```
self._chart.axisX(self._line_time).setRange(                  
    QDateTime(date[value_min]), QDateTime(date[value_max]))
```

Обратите внимание:

- axisXx <---> **axisX**
- _line_tme <---> **_line_time**,
- qt[...] <---> **QDateTime(date**[...])